# hammer.js,pinch Gesture block event of subelement,How to resolve it?

Tags: events, hammer.js, pinch

(div id="d-cont") used Pinch and Pan:

```
<div id="d-cont">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <span><em id="A1-8" class="full-bin"><b>A1-8</b></em></span>
               </li>
           </ul>
       </div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  function show(event){
  //display text
  $('#d-cont').find('b').css('display','none');
  $(event.target).find('b').css('display','block');
  };
  //bind function
  $('.full-bin').click(function(event){show(event)});
  $('.semi-bin').click(function(event){show(event)});
  });

</script>
```

I do this to set hammer.Manager;

```
var el = document.querySelector("#d-cont");
var mc = new hammer.Manager(el);
var Pan = new hammer.Pan({ threshold: 0, pointers: 0 });
var Pinch = new hammer.Pinch({threshold: 0, pointers: 2});
Pinch.recognizeWith(Pan);
mc.add(Pan);
mc.add(Pinch);
mc.set({domEvents:true});
mc.on("panstart panmove", onPan);
mc.on("panend",onPanend);
mc.on("pinchmove", onPinch);
```

But the click events never be invoked before iOS9,and I can't solve it, help please;